# How to represent the difference between two time series with a bar plot in the same chart?

Tags: r, time-series, bar-chart

For example, if we have two time series `a` and `b`:

```
time <- seq(as.Date("1999-06-15"),as.Date("2008-06-15") , by= "years")
a <- c(22.3,24.1,35,35,35.9,39.2,34.8,31.5,29.1,25.8)    
b <- c(22,24.9,31,34,37.5,36.3,32.1,29.7,28.6,23.9)
plot(as.Date(time),a,type="l",xlab="Date",ylab="T(°C)")
lines(as.Date(time),b,col=2)
```

Is there a way that my plot will look like the image example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [the first answer by markus (before the edit)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52084621/3817004) contained a major flaw which has caused the bars showing the residuals *to be twice as high as expected*. This will become immediately visible when the filling of the bars is coloured according to `key`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data_frame(time, a, b) %>%
  mutate(diff_a_b = a - b) %>% 
  gather(key, value, a, b) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = value, color = key)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = diff_a_b, fill = key))
```

[image]

The root cause is that `diff_a_b` is not treated as variable when reshaping from wide to long format:

```
data_frame(time, a, b) %>%
  mutate(diff_a_b = a - b) %>% 
  gather(key, value, a, b)
```

So `diff_a_b` appears twice for each `time` value:

> ```
> # A tibble: 20 x 4
>    time       diff_a_b key   value
>    <date>        <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
>  1 1999-06-15    0.3   a      22.3
>  2 2000-06-15   -0.800 a      24.1
>  3 2001-06-15    4     a      35  
>  4 2002-06-15    1     a      35  
>  5 2003-06-15   -1.6   a      35.9
>  6 2004-06-15    2.9   a      39.2
>  7 2005-06-15    2.70  a      34.8
>  8 2006-06-15    1.8   a      31.5
>  9 2007-06-15    0.5   a      29.1
> 10 2008-06-15    1.9   a      25.8
> 11 1999-06-15    0.3   b      22  
> 12 2000-06-15   -0.800 b      24.9
> 13 2001-06-15    4     b      31  
> 14 2002-06-15    1     b      34  
> 15 2003-06-15   -1.6   b      37.5
> 16 2004-06-15    2.9   b      36.3
> 17 2005-06-15    2.70  b      32.1
> 18 2006-06-15    1.8   b      29.7
> 19 2007-06-15    0.5   b      28.6
> 20 2008-06-15    1.9   b      23.9
> ```

As the default for `geom_col()` is `position = "stack"` the two values are stacked on top of each other.

#### Quick fixes for markus' answer

If position is changed to `"dodge"` then [markus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52084621/3817004) would show the expected result

```
data_frame(time, a, b) %>%
  mutate(diff_a_b = a - b) %>% 
  gather(key, value, a, b) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = value, color = key)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = diff_a_b), position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Another fix would be to use `geom_linerange()` where each segment will be plotted twice:

```
data_frame(time, a, b) %>%
  mutate(diff_a_b = a - b) %>% 
  gather(key, value, a, b) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = value, color = key)) + 
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = diff_a_b), size = 3)
```

[image]

#### "Tidy" approach

IMHO, the correct ("tidy") approach is to treat `diff_a_b` as third variable / time series when reshaping and to use the `data` parameter when creating the geoms:

```
data_frame(time, a, b) %>%
  mutate(diff_a_b = a - b) %>% 
  gather(, , -time) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(col = key), data = function(x) filter(x, key != "diff_a_b")) + 
  geom_col(data = function(x) filter(x, key == "diff_a_b"))
```

[image]

#### `data.table` and `ggplot2`

For those who prefer `data.table` for data munging:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
long <- data.table(time, a, b)[
  , diff_a_b := a - b][
    , melt(.SD, "time")]
ggplot() + aes(time, value) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = variable), data = long[variable != "diff_a_b"]) + 
  geom_col(data = long[variable == "diff_a_b"])
```

Comment: That's a good answer. Didn't notice the mistake. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `ggplot2`'s `geom_line` and `geom_col`.

```
library(tidyverse)
DF_bar <- mutate(DF, diff_a_b = a - b)

DF %>% 
  gather(key, value, a, b) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = value, col = key)) + 
  geom_col(data = DF_bar, aes(y = diff_a_b)) # or geom_bar(data = DF_bar, aes(y = diff_a_b), stat = "identity")
```

In the first step I created a new data set that contains the variable, `diff_a_b`, which is, well, the difference between `a` and `b`.

Next, I reshaped your data from wide to long such that we can map column `key` to the colour aesthetic in `geom_line`. Finally, I use `DF_bar` in `geom_col` to plot `diff_a_b`.

**data**

```
DF <- data.frame(time = seq(as.Date("1999-06-15"),as.Date("2008-06-15"), by= "years"),
                 a = c(22.3,24.1,35,35,35.9,39.2,34.8,31.5,29.1,25.8),
                 b = c(22,24.9,31,34,37.5,36.3,32.1,29.7,28.6,23.9))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you markus, i wonder if there is a solution to represent the natural scale of residuals in bar plots, or within your method they'll always be rescaled for being appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome @spectral_lion_18. But I am not sure I understand what you mean by "the natural scale of residuals in bar plots". The height of each bar is simply the difference between `a` and `b`.

Comment: Yes, I mean in height, because the difference between a and b in graph looks like twice the value of real difference, and then i try: `geom_col(aes(y = (1*abs(diff_a_b/2))))`

Comment: ...and that's what i've looked for, so thank you very very much for your help, i appreciate it.

Comment: The reason for the bars to be twice as high as expected is that `diff_a_b` appears twice for each `time` value after `gather()` and `geom_col()` uses `position = "stack"` by default. For fixes and alternative approaches see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52087023/3817004), please.

Comment: @spectral_lion_18 I see now! Thanks Uwe for pointing this out.